# Using the existing paths to create a mask to a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath, masking

I have a `UIButton` inside of which I draw three `UIBezierPaths` so that they create a triangle. Now, I need to fill the area of that triangle, but I don't know how to get that region. Using `setFill` (and then, `fill`) on the paths doesn't work.

Maybe, it is possible to achieve this by masking the view. If it is the case, I wonder how to achieve that (to create a triangular mask) by using existing paths (which, again, are set so that they create a triangular).

How can I fill the area between the three paths? If you know how to do that, I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about instantiating a new `UIView` and using the path you just drew as a clipping mask? Then add the newly clipped object as a subview to your `UIButton`.

Comment: Yeah, finally it worked. Thanks. But it can be achieved easier by just setting the endpoints of the path so it creates a triangle and then just filling it.